# formtastic select, one entry selected as default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, formtastic

I have an input which I render :as => :select. I would like one option to be selected as default. How would I go about that?

Thanks,
Hendrik

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So set a preselected answer you have to associate your object with the desired value.

```
countries = ['USA','Germany']
@user.country = countries.first
```

That works for me.

Answer (score 11):

If you are not making a form off of a model.

```
= semantic_form_for :report do |f|
  = f.inputs name: 'Choose a Report Year' do
    = f.input :report_year, collection: options_for_select(['2010', '2011', '2012', '2013'], '2012')
    = f.action :submit, label: 'Submit Year', as: :button
```

Comment: :collection => options_for_select if you don't use haml (comment only oriented for noobs like me :D)

Comment: the answer uses Ruby 1.9 hash syntax - nothing to do with haml vs. anything else.

Answer (score 2):

You could read about this in the formtastic wiki. Always check gem readme before asking anything. Here is a [link.](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic/wiki/Deprecation-of-%3aselected-option) Good luck!

Comment: sorry. I am rails noob : ). So the default depends on the active record relationship?

Comment: No problem. As said in wiki you can pass `options_for_select([“Page”, “Organization”, “Promotion”], @banner.entity_type)` first argument is collection of options, second is default selected value.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have an associated model into the semantic_form_for you can do this:

```
f.inputs do
  f.input :service_type, :as => :radio,
          :collection => [
                           ['Group', 'Group', { :'checked' => 'checked' }],
                           ['Device', 'Device', {}]
                         ]
end
```